# Datanode size in hadoop cluster increasing fast

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

I have a hadoop cluster with 2-master nodes and 3-data nodes. I am running an spark-streaming application. Application is streaming file from s3 and after processing storing result to s3. I'm not able to understand why data node storage getting full without storing data on hdfs.
Location:
/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-1127218281-IP-1662958210599/current/finalized/subdir0

Please help how can i handle this situation?

Comment: Seems like you're using EMR? Yes, Spark stores temporary data in local HDFS for jobs

Comment: No, I'm not using EMR. I'm using aws server and hadoop-cluster setup manually.